# Call decorator with class variable in python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Probably I am approaching the problem in the wrong way and there is a simpler solution, but here is my problem.

I have a decorator defined like this:

```
def my_decorator(argument):
    def wrap(f):
       def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
           .... # does something with argument
       return wrapped_f
    return wrap
```

then I defined a class that looks like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(argument):
        self.argument = argument

    @my_decorator(self.argument)  # !this is an error! 
    def my_method(self):
       .... # does something
```

Clearly what I wrote is wrong because at the decorator level I cannot access `self`, but what's the right approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could have the decorator access `self.argument` inside `wrapped_f`:

```
def mydecorator(f):
   def wrapped_f(self, *args, **kwargs):
       argument = self.argument
       .... # does something with argument
       return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
   return wrapped_f
return wrap
```

If the variable being passed as `argument` changes depending on the function being decorated, you can pass it to the decorator as a string and use `getattr` to get it from `self`:

```
def my_decorator(arg_name):
    def wrap(f):
       def wrapped_f(self, *args, **kwargs):
           argument = getattr(self, arg_name)
           .... # does something with argument
       return wrapped_f
    return wrap

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, argument):
        self.argument = argument

    @my_decorator("argument")
    def my_method(self):
       .... does something
```

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something! Much easier than what I was thinking! Thanks!

Comment: But how is `self` passed to `wrapped_f`? I get a `TypeError: my_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

Comment: @Wtower Python automatically passes `self` to `my_method`, because `my_method()` is an instance method of `MyClass`. It sounds like you're decorating a regular function, which doesn't get the `self` parameter automatically.

Comment: @dano thank you for your reply. No I am not trying to decorate a regular function. The error comes in the `my_decorator:wrap_f:wrapped_f` function, and I was referring to that `self`.

Comment: @Wtower Hmm, I just tried running my example (I filled in the `....` sections with some stub code), and it worked fine. I think I'd have to see your code to tell you what the problem is.